# How to safely remove eSATA drive when it's not in the Safely Remove Hardware dialog - XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, esata

**How can I safely remove my external eSATA disk on Windows XP? I want to avoid any workarounds that involve reinstalling, rebooting, and/or reconfiguring the drive.**

I found a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/289581/how-to-safely-remove-esata-drive-when-its-not-in-the-safely-remove-hardware-dial) but I'm using Windows XP instead of Windows 7. The answer provided there makes no sense to me, as I want nothing but to safely remove the hard disk. I don't want to change the options in any way - I especially don't think that disabling caching will be useful to anyone (as I'm not expecting a power outage any time soon!).

Note that unlike my C: drive, the drive I want to switch off does not appear in the "Safely remove..." menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into either Device Manager or Computer Management-Disk Storage.

From there, you can disable the drive or under Disk Storage you can make the drive offline.

**edit**

The only other option to make your drive appear on the *Safely remove* IS a reconfiguration, which is to set the drive as removeable under Device Manager.

As said below, disabling a drive under Device Manager does **not** remove the drive from the list. It just puts a gray arrow on it.  Switching it offline is under Computer Management, which I stated above.

**edit**

To batch this, you use the **diskpart remove** *drive_letter*  command to dismount the drive.

Comment: Disabling the disk falls into the category "reconfiguring" and is even worse than simple disabling the caching (the device disappears from the list, which makes re-enabling harder). I haven't found any possibility to switch it off-line.

Comment: Disabling a device **doesn't** remove the device from Device Manager.  Even if it did, rescanning your system for hardware changes (which device manager also does) will redetect it.

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't get removed from the from Device Manager, but it gets removed from Computer Management/Disk Storage (which is what I meant). I hate Windows forcing me to make permanent changes for something as trivial as stopping a device.

Comment: If the Drive has a dynamic volume, it doesn't disappear. It's something you can batchfile also. I have two eSata docks myself and I use an autohotkey script  to eject them from the system.

Comment: It's not dynamic. I'd like to create a batch script using `diskpart`, however `remove f:` says `The arguments you specified for this command are not valid.` which is (as usually) of no help. It looks like it should be `remove letter=f`, but this complains again... Finally it works... unless the volume number changes! **How could anybody invent something as user-hostile as this?**

Comment: Windows has the **optimize for removal** option.  But per your specifications, that option isn't a solution you are looking for.  So thus, any other solution isn't going to be a point+click affair.

Comment: It's getting better and better: "DiskPart successfully removed the drive letter, but your computer needs to be rebooted before the changes take effect." :D:D:D

Comment: Ignore the reboot message.  I never reboot either.

Comment: Actually, I am a command line fan. However, using such a strange CLI and giving such perfectly non-informative messages drives me crazy. But forget it, I've accepted your answer and I'm gonna struggle with `diskpart` myself or maybe ask another question.

Comment: If you are a command line fan, then this should be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 2):

http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm

It is free and works great for disconnecting eSata drives.